# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes or takes forever to boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, swap, crash

When booting Ubuntu 18.04, it shows this error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemct1 status swapfile.swap' for details
```

and then it takes gets stuck on the Ubuntu loading screen.

The output of running `sudo parted -l` in the live installer:

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 2      525MB   209GB   209GB   primary   ntfs
 3      209GB   210GB   528MB   primary   ntfs         diag
 4      210GB   1000GB  790GB   extended               lba
 5      210GB   968GB   758GB   logical   ntfs
 6      968GB   1000GB  32.2GB  logical   ext4

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  
/dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Model: PLDS DVD-RW DA8AESH (scsi)                                         
Disk /dev/sr0: 1922MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      1880MB  1883MB  2392kB               EFI
```

Comment: 1. you done your **swap** partitioning completely? 2. if yes then follow the error and see that swap file

Comment: I am not able to get into ubuntu even. It gets stuck at the loading screen.

Comment: This is not an answer. Asking about more details should be done in comments

Comment: If you boot into recovery mode from grub menu, can you get to command line? Then run the suggested command to see details on issue. If not you may need to boot live installer and temporarily edit fstab to not load swap. Do you have swap file or swap partition? Post this: `sudo parted -l` from live installer.

Comment: Boot into live installer is the same as booting from ubuntu installation media?

Comment: Yes, the live installer is an Ubuntu install disk and full working Ubuntu live systems. Live installer is not as fast as full install and not updateable as configured using default install software which will be updated after install to very latest versions.

Comment: So i run the live installer and run sudo parted -l command in the terminal?

Comment: Please post output. Did you try yet? And did you try booting to command line using recovery mode? And run this and post to question above: `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f` to see if UUID match on swap.

Comment: maybe their is  a **grub loader** problem occurs because you say that Ubuntu stuck at the loading screen

Comment: I have edited my original post and posted the output of sudo parted -l by booting in a live installer. Can you recommended some edits above as I still don't know yet?

Comment: After selecting Ubuntu from the grub menu, it goes straight to the error as mentioned in the question. I suppose there is a problem with the swap file or partition.

Comment: I booted into recovery mode and ran the above commands. Running cat /etc/fstab gave me a swapfile with no UUID and nothing else. Running lsblk -f gave me sda6 as swap with a UUID.

Comment: Swap files don't require swap partitioning.

Comment: You never posted this: See 'systemct1 status swapfile.swap' for details which is the original suggestion.